What caused localized cracking and peeling of wall paint and how should I go about fixing it?
We just discovered this damage to our house's wall that was behind a bunch of furniture. Does anyone have any idea what could cause this? It's inside the house, and in a well ventilated and cleaned area. I am not sure what caused it.



If that's the only area with this sort of damage, and there are other areas with the same materials and coatings, I'd suspect moisture. It could've been from a spill or it could be coming from outside. You'll have to do your own investigation.

Moisture test
Use 8d (or any) nail and push it in by hand (no hammer)
If it goes in easy then you have a moisture problem.
Someone before you tried to cover it up (as visible in the photos) with lots of drywall mud, without repairing the moisture source.
You will have to open and repair the source of the moisture.

...and if the OP determines they have a moisture problem, then how should they proceed?

@RMDman   Ask a new question.  It looks like a moisture problem.  If an on going problem or the surface was damp/not prep well when painting.

@RMDman feel free to ask that question, hopefully you learned something about the moisture test

If you would read, that question was asked in the OP original.  Your "answer" only gave a method to indicate possible moisture. It offered no insight into how to expand to find a possible cause, or subsequent cure.
